# UICollectionView cell is disappearing when dragging out of initial bounds (Swift3, CollectionView, Drag and Drop)

Tags: ios, swift3, drag-and-drop, uicollectionview

I have a problem, when dragging cell out of initial bounds.

On drag, I take value from UILongPressGestureRecognizer location and set cell "center" property to this location.

The problem occurs when I scroll down, below initial bounds, the cell doesn't show on the view (although there are cells existing down, probably loaded after first view appearing). When I scroll little up, within same take (press), cell shows up again.

I tried several things

- cashing cells, so view alway get the same cell instance on reload
- override func viewDidLayoutSubviews which lead in endless loop
  `override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
  super.viewDidLayoutSubviews() 
  myCollection.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
  }`
- collectionView?.clipsToBounds = false

None of these worked for me. Could you help me? Thanks!!!

Comment: are you using UIDragInteraction ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. No, I'm using UILongPressGestureRecognizer to implement dran and drop.